# Google analytics events in behavior section not showing up

Tags: google-analytics

in my site i have google analytics tag coded it works in real-time but when i go to behavior nothing show up.. it says there is only one event, in the graph section but down in the report section there's nothing.

[image: sample]
![sample][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using GA free, please be advised that the data will be visible in reports within 24-72 hrs. If you see the data in real-time reports, be assured it will show up in the reports in due time.